# Knockout Cart example, Drop Down selected info

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/descending/adNuR/2523/

So this is the Knockout Js Car Editor sample and I added one thing, the Get Info link. I need to be able to add items and get the selected items for that line when the user clicks get info.

How on earth can I achieve this? I'm stumped

```
var CartLine = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.category = ko.observable();
    self.product = ko.observable();
    self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
    self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.product() ? self.product().price * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
    });

    // Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
    self.category.subscribe(function () {
        self.product(undefined);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to `CartLine` to get the info:

```
self.getInfo = function () {
    var category = self.category() ? self.category().name : "";
    var product = self.product() ? self.product().name : "";
    alert(category + ": " + product + ": " + self.quantity());
}
```

Bind it to the click event...

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: getInfo'>Get Info</a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/2524/

Answer (score 0):

make new method

```
self.getInfo=function(d){
   alert("Category is "+d.category().name+" and product is"+d.product().name+" and quantity is "+d.quantity());
}
```

and in html add this binding

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click:$parent.getInfo,visible: product'>Get Info</a>
```

working example on http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/2525/

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect as well!